# Why matrix inverse is not numerical stable?

Tags: matrix, linear, computational-statistics

I was told by many people, many times,

> Never explicitly compute matrix inverse, because it is not numerical stable. Instead, use LU, QR, SVD decomposition to solve the linear system.

But why? Is that true for some matrixes (say symmetric positive definite matrix), inverse is better than other?

Comment: An excellent resource for questions of this nature--because it gives understandable, relatively less technical accounts of the issues than almost any other book--is [Numerical Recipes](http://numerical.recipes/).

Comment: Computing inverses is generally expensive - especially if the matrix is ill-conditioned.

Comment: Post your question at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ .